# TLB flushing within a given virtual address range

Tags: arm, flush, tlb

I know that I can flush a TLB entry for a given virtual address as follows in ARMv7, VMSA

```
mcr p15, 4, c8, c7, 1, $VA ; TLBIMVAH
```

I've failed to find a single instruction that can flush a TLB entry for a range of virtual address (e.g., from A to B). All I can do is loop over the virtual address ranges and issue the above instruction over and over again.

My question is here: Is there any efficient method or golden instruction that flushes a given range of virtual address?

And, just out of curiosity, if there is no such kind of instruction, could you tell me which constraints make this instruction impossible?